# How do i access the list of email addresses that bounced

Tags: civimail

I am using SparkPost for mail delivery of CiviCRM mass mailing.  I can see the types of bounces that we had but i haven't found a list of email addresses that bounced.  How do i find the email addresses that bounced?

Answer (score 2):

Go to CiviMail -> Scheduled and Sent Mailings -> under Action, in the far right column of the Mailing Name line, select Report -> Select Report to the right of Bounces

Answer (score 2):

You can also perform searches for Bounces via Advanced Search provided that your Display Settings include it at civicrm/admin/setting/preferences/display?reset=1